# How to change all values of a particular column in jqxGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid

I'm using `jqxGrid`. I have a column which has `columntype` as `dropdownlist`. I want to change all values of this column If the user tries to change dropdown value in any row. So I have dropdown which has value as yes and no. If the user changes any dropdown from yes to no, it should change all dropdown of this particular column.

```
{
text: 'First Row is Header',
width: 150,
datafield: 'header',
columntype: 'dropdownlist',
createeditor: function(row, column, editor) {
var headerList = ["Yes", "No"];
editor.jqxDropDownList({
autoDropDownHeight: true,
source: headerList
})
}
}
```

Comment: so you're saying you have yes and no's all throughout this column and if someone changes one of them you want them all changed to the same selection the user chooses?

Comment: @Keith exactly, all rows for this column should have same values

Comment: do you have a link to a jqgrid that has a dropdown as a value for a column?